# вывод tv поля по id_from_crm

Tags: modx, migx

Имеются форма `[ { "caption": "Данные", "fields": [ { "field": "name", "caption": "Имя менеджера", "inputTVtype": "text" }, { "field": "post", "caption": "Должность", "inputTVtype": "text" }, { "field": "image", "caption": "Изображение", "inputTVtype": "image" }, { "field": "image-placeholder", "caption": "Превью", "inputTVtype": "image" }, { "field": "regions-list", "caption": "Регионы", "inputTV": "regions" }, { "field": "is_slider", "caption": "Отображать в карусели", "inputTV": "status" } , { "field": "is_slider_form", "caption": "Отображать в карусели (форма)", "inputTV": "status" } , { "field": "id_from_crm", "caption": "ID пользователя в CRM" } ] }]`

нужно вывести имя, и должность по id_from_crm, пытаюсь вывести так `[[!getImageList? &tvname=`employees `&docid=`11 `&limit=`1 `&tpl=`@CODE: [[+name]], [[+id_from_crm]] `]]`
но выводит постоянно одного человека, если поставить рандомное, то будет всё верно выводить, но мне нужно что бы конкретно по id_from_crm

Comment: Не очень понятно, как должно выводить, если просто все записи то у вас стоит limit=1 - он ограничивает количество выводимых записей, будет выводить только 1 запись, если нужно отобрать определенную запись, то надо использовать условие where к примеру where= {"id_from_crm":"1"} уточните вопрос, или приведите как-то набор данных и что должно из них выводиться

Comment: вроде то что мне нужно

Comment: Тогда оформляю как ответ, хотя не очень понятно, что именно из этого вам помогло решить ваш вопрос. Если ответ Вам помог, отметьте пожалуйста его принятым.

Comment: а могу ли я  where= {"id_from_crm":"СЮДА"} передать само tv поле ?

Comment: да, можно, ставлю плюс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам надо вывести все записи то у вас стоит

```
 &limit=`1`
```

он ограничивает количество выводимых записей, будет выводить только 1 запись. Для показа всех записей измените параметр на 0

Если нужно отобрать определенную запись, то надо использовать условие отбора `where` к примеру:

```
&where = `{"id_from_crm":"1"}`
```